# Can I reference other slots in a defstruct?

Tags: common-lisp

In common lisp I've noticed that I can write this:

```
(defun foo (&key (a 1) (b 2) (c (+ a b))) (print (+ a b c)))
```

And when I call `(foo)`, `6` is printed. So the argument `c` can refer to values set for `a` and `b`. But I can't seem to find a way to do something similar with `defstruct`. Something like:

```
CL-USER> (defstruct thing a b c)
THING
CL-USER> (setq q (make-thing :a 1 :b 2 :c (+ a b)))
; Evaluation aborted
CL-USER> (setq q (make-thing :a 1 :b 2 :c (+ :a :b)))
; Evaluation aborted
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using `:constructor` option of `defstruct`.

```
CL-USER> (defstruct (thing
                      (:constructor make-thing (&key a b (c (+ a b)))))
           a b c)
THING
CL-USER> (make-thing :a 1 :b 2)
#S(THING :A 1 :B 2 :C 3)
```

For more info, see CLHS entry for [`defstruct`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defstr.htm#defstruct).

Answer (score 3):

Not that way.  But using Lisp reader tricks you can do:

```
(make-thing :a #1=1 :b #2=2 :c (+ #1# #2#))
```

Otherwise use `defclass` and specialize the generic function `shared-initialize`.

Note that these reader macros will reference the *form*, not the result of evaluating it.  Thus

```
(make-thing :id #1=(generate-unique-id) :my-id-is #1#)
```

will make a `thing` with *two distinct* calls to `generate-unique-id`.